# Eclipse php ERROR You don't have permission to access

Tags: php

Otro problema que me quita el sueño.
Esta vez con una proyecto con el *patrón MVC* que conecta a una *Base de Datos* y me muestra todos los registro en una tabla. En cada fila tengo una botón para eliminar y un botón para actualizar el registro.

Hay que tener en cuenta en cuenta que se ha hecho en **eclipse php** y **servidor WAMP proyecto**  guardado en workspace:

> C:\wamp64\www\MVC.

Proyecto MVC:

```
index.php

  carpeta modelo/
    conexionBD_Modelo.php , 
    ObtenerRegistro_Modelo.php

  carpeta vista /
    MostrarResultados_Vista.php

  carpeta controlador /
    eliminar.php , 
    UsoModelo_Controlador.php
```

Aqui el problema :
Al mostrar los registros en una tabla con los botones eliminar y actualizar este es el codigo para eliminar

```
foreach ($arrayProductos as $registro){

    echo "<tr><td>" .$registro['Codigo']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['Seccion']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['NombreArt']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['Precio']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['Fecha']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['Importado']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$registro['PaisOrigen']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><a name = 'eliminar' href='controlador\eliminar.php?id_eliminar=" . $registro['Codigo'] . "'>eliminar</a>,</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='paginaDestino.php'?id=" .$registro['Codigo']. "><input type='button' name ='eliminar' value='eliminar'></a> </td></tr>";

}
```

Como podeis ver en el `href` envio a la pagina `eliminar.php` la variable `id_eliminar`. Bien pues al pinchar sobre este enlace me sale en la página:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /MVC/controlador/eliminar.php on
>   this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4 Server at localhost Port 80

Pero si saco el archivo eliminar.php de la carpeta controlador y lo pongo en la raiz de MVC como index.php. osea fuera de todas las subcarpetas  y cambio el codigo de

```
echo "<td><a name = 'eliminar' href='controlador\eliminar.php?id_eliminar=" . $registro['Codigo'] . "'>eliminar</a>,</td>";
```

a

```
echo "<td><a name = 'eliminar' href='eliminar.php?id_eliminar=" . $registro['Codigo'] . "'>eliminar</a>,</td>";
```

Entonces el código funciona bien y elimina los registros

Alguna solución, algo que no veo , algo que me estoy saltando ??

Answer (score 0):

Si está buscando una solución rápida y LA SEGURIDAD NO ES UN ASUNTO, es decir, env de desarrollo, omita y lea la respuesta original en su lugar.

Muchos escenarios pueden llevar a 403 Forbidden:

**A. Directory Indexes (de mod_autoindex.c)**

Cuando accede a un directorio y no se encuentra ningún archivo predeterminado en este directorio Y los Índices de Opciones de Apache no están habilitados para este directorio.

**A.1. Ejemplo de opción DirectoryIndex**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html default.php welcome.php
```

Si se establece, apache mostrará el contenido del directorio si no se encuentra ningún archivo predeterminado (de la opción  anterior)

Si no se cumple ninguna de las condiciones anteriores

**Recibirás un 403 Prohibido**

Recomendaciones:

- No debe permitir el listado de directorios a menos que REALMENTE lo necesite.
- Restringir el índice predeterminado DirectoryIndex al mínimo.
- Si desea modificar, restrinja la modificación SOLAMENTE al directorio necesario, por ejemplo, use archivos .htaccess o coloque su modificación dentro de la directiva .

la solucion mas sencilla es darle permiso de escritura/modificaciones a tu carpeta del proyecto, por ejemplo de esta manera:

use este script  para darle permisos a tu archivos/carpetas

```
# setting permissions for /var/www/mysite.com

# read permission ONLY for the owner 
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.com 400 

# add execute for folders only
find /var/www/mysite.com -type d -exec chmod -R u+x {} \;

# allow file uploads 
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.com/public/uploads u+w

# allow log writing to this folder
chmod -R /var/www/mysite.com/logs/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoy me he dado cuenta que el error que me da

You don't have permission to access /MVC/**controladorliminar.php** on this server.
Este es el enlace donde envió la variable y llamo la función

```
echo "<td><a name = 'eliminar' href='controlador\eliminar.php?id_eliminar=" . $registro['Codigo'] . "'>eliminar</a></td>";
```

lo estraño esta en el controladorliminar.php

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o una edicion de pregunta mal puesta?